# Leap Year Messing up Future Date Calculations

Tags: c#, blazor, calculator, leap-year

So My coworker and I have been in the works on creating a Blazor app for an expiration date calculator for the labs at our company. We are basically almost done until we realized that leap years exist and are messing up the calculation.

We know how to check for a leap year but the thing is, once we account for a leap year (e.g 2024) every calculation for every year after that turns up wrong (e.g 2025,2026, etc.).

We don't know how to remedy this beyond just creating a check if it's a leap year or not since the calculation is just messed up every year after that... thoughts or has anyone else run into this issue?
The logic part of the code  is listed below:

```
@code {
private RecordEditContext recordEditContext = new RecordEditContext(new());
private ExpirationDate ExpiryDate = new ExpirationDate();
private string errorMessage = string.Empty;

private bool IsError => this.errorMessage != string.Empty;

private void CalculateExpiryDate()
{
    this.errorMessage = string.Empty;
    this.ExpiryDate.Value = DateTime.MinValue;
    this.recordEditContext.SetToClean();

    if ((recordEditContext.IsBeforeDate == false) && (recordEditContext.IsPlate == false) && (recordEditContext.ShelfLife >= 90))
    {
        this.ExpiryDate.Value = (recordEditContext.MixDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(recordEditContext.ShelfLife)) - TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        this.ExpiryDate.Format = ExpirationDate.ExpiryDateFormat.MonthYear;
        DateTime expDay = this.ExpiryDate.Value;
        DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(expDay.Year, expDay.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(expDay.Year, expDay.Month));

        return;
    }

    if ((recordEditContext.IsBeforeDate == true) || (recordEditContext.IsPlate == true) || (recordEditContext.ShelfLife < 90))
    {
        this.ExpiryDate.Value = (recordEditContext.MixDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(recordEditContext.ShelfLife)).AddDays(-1);
        this.ExpiryDate.Format = ExpirationDate.ExpiryDateFormat.YearMonthDay;
        return;
    }

    this.errorMessage = "Please Try Again. Information Not Satisfactory.";
}
```

let me know if you guys need more information!

Comment: Your expiration policy is in terms of ***days***, not years, so it's behaving correctly. Leap years aren't relevant. If something degrades after 10 days, but--whoops!--Feburary 29 is in the middle of that, it's not magically going to last another day.

Comment: [And THEN you get a call from the astrophysicist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)

Comment: You need to tell us what your requirements are. What do you want the program to do? The only information you've given us so far is that leap years are messing up the calculations. *But what does that actually mean?*

Comment: It's not clear to me what the error is here. Although I do see that you create `endOfMonth` for some reason (it's never used) right before you `return`. Also, your second `if` clause could just be an `else`, right?

Comment: @JimMischel  
So the 1st if statement is supposed to be the "new format" in which the date is displayed as MM/YYYY but when theres a leap year, the years after the leap year in question are calculating the wrong month. It is subtracting 2 months instead of 1 month if the info fits into the first if statement parameters (Is not before XX/XX date, is not a plate product, and the shelf life is greater than or equal to 90 days)

The other if statement is for the old format (YYYY/MM/DD) but that one is calculating correctly, the error is within the first "if" statement 

I hope that clarifies

Comment: @RufusL ^ i wanted to mention you in this comment as well but it wouldnt let me

Comment: The test cases are 11/01, 11/30, 12/01, 12/31 , 2022 - 2024 , shelf life 365 and 1095 and i can edit the post to provide the full code if you would like to see it more in depth @JimMischel

Comment: Again, your expiration policy is in terms of days. 365 days != 1 year so you can't expect a calculation using days to always yield the same thing as a calculation using years. Unless you can define the expiration policy in terms of fractional days equivalent to a year, i.e. 365.242199, you can't get the same thing.

Comment: @madreflection that explanation made more sense after your first comment thank you for the clairification, ill bring that up tp my coworker

Comment: @Sahar I don't want to see your code just yet. What I'm interested in is a description *in words* of exactly what you want your code to do. Do your expirations have to be expressed in days? Or can they be expressed in weeks? Months? Years? Don't just answer my questions. Rather, update your question to provide a full, clear, detailed description of the process that you're trying to automate. Remember, all we know about your problem is what you tell us. The more clearly you can explain the problem, the more likely we will be able to help you solve it.

Comment: Ideally your code should be simplified to something we can copy/paste and run on our own (without external dependencies) - just the part that's causing the date calculation issue. Then some sample data should be provided, along with the expected output and actual output. That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like the business wants a product that expires to show the expiration date as 3 years as shown on a calendar minus 30 days. At least from what I can tell. So specifically you want November 1, 2022 with a 3 year expiration date to be November 1, 2025 minus 30 days. To do this, you cannot count by days alone as you are.

A reproduction of what you're doing now:

```
    //this is what you're currently doing
    //(recordEditContext.MixDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(recordEditContext.ShelfLife)) - TimeSpan.FromDays(30)
    DateTime MixDate = new DateTime(2022, 12, 01);
    TimeSpan ShelfLife = TimeSpan.FromDays(1095);
    TimeSpan ThirtyDays = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    var TimeAsIs = (MixDate + ShelfLife) - ThirtyDays;
    Console.WriteLine($"### original ###\nMixed: {MixDate} Expires: {TimeAsIs}");
```

How you might fix most of the issue:

```
    //This sets the day of expiration based on the mix date and then calculates the date you need.
    //If you need it to be November 1, 2025 minus 30 days
    //because it was mixed on November 1 2022, this is how.
    DateTime ExpirationDateIsThreeYears = new DateTime(MixDate.Year + 3, MixDate.Month, MixDate.Day);
    var NewTime = ExpirationDateIsThreeYears - ThirtyDays;
    Console.WriteLine($"### new ###\nMixed: {MixDate} Expires: {NewTime}");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

This outputs:

```
### original ###
Mixed: 12/1/2022 12:00:00 AM Expires: 10/31/2025 12:00:00 AM
### new ###
Mixed: 12/1/2022 12:00:00 AM Expires: 11/1/2025 12:00:00 AM
```

Basically if I understand your problem correctly, you can solve it by simply adding 1 or 3 years to the MixDate year and then subtracting 30 days. This would still cause an issue counting backwards through February 29 if the product expires between March 1 and March 29 on a leap year, but it eliminates the overwhelming majority of the issue since 11/12 cases will only count forward through February 29. Hope this helps!

Comment: `new DateTime(MixDate.Year + 3, MixDate.Month, MixDate.Day)` what happens if `MixDate` is Feb. 29th?

Comment: Maybe `var NewTime = MixDate.AddYears(3).AddDays(-30);` would work better?

Comment: Yeah I think that solution might work better, because you wont count backwards to February 29 if there isn't one! I'll edit this in a bit!